# Can¨t find where the issue lie. ERROR: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I understand the concept of the error, in some methods etc does not return values, but can't find where the wrongly put code is. I am following a book when learning to write C# code and I have double checked in the book but can't find any help.

I'll paste the code below:
The error mainly considers the 'public override string ToString(); as a problem area.

```
using System;

class TidPunkt
{
    //instansvariabler
    int tim, min, sek;
    bool visaSek = true;

    //Metoder
    public void Sätt(int t, int m, int s)
    {
        if (t <= 0 && t < 24 && m <= 0 && m < 60 && s <= 0 && s < 60)
        {
            tim = t; min = m; sek = s;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
    }
    public void SättVisaSek(bool visa)
    {
        visaSek = visa;

    }

    public int AvläsTim()
    {
        return tim;
    }
    public int AvläsMin()
    {
        return min;
    }
    public int AvläsSek()
    {
        return sek;
    }
    public void Ticka()
    {
        if(++sek == 60)
        {
            sek = 0; ++min;
        }
        if(min == 60)
        {
            min = 0; ++tim;
        }
        if(tim == 24)
        {
            tim = 0;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string tid = tim + ":" + min;
        if (visaSek)
        {
            tid = tid + ":" + sek;
            return tid;
        }
    }

}
```

Thankful for all feedback and help!
Thanks!

Comment: What happens for that function if `visaSek` is false?

Comment: Nothing according to the book

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler yields... the function ToString is not returning a `string` in all options to run the fuction.

For example, if `visaSek` is `False`, the function is not returning a `string` as its prototype defines.

you need to add a `return` statement to handle this..

Example.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string tid = tim + ":" + min;
    if (visaSek)
    {
        tid = tid + ":" + sek;
        return tid;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I would explain why OP needs to return something. It's because the signature of the method has a string return type.

Comment: Thanks for the help, couidn't grasp where that return statement would be. But, it works fine now.